# Using copyindex() for subnet name creates error as a duplicate resource

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

I've tried using copyIndex() to create subnets with different names but I get the error

```
        "message": "Resource
/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/ has two child
resources with the same name
([parameters('subnets').subnetProperties[copyIndex('subnets')].name)).
```

But I followed documation to use copy and this is what I've been using, so I'm not sure why is wouldn't move to the next name property:

```
 "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
        "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
        "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "tags": "[parameters('virtualNetworkTags')]",
        "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
             "[parameters('vNetAddressSpaces')]"
          ]
        },
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "subnets",
                    "count": "[parameters('numberOfSubnets')]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "[parameters('subnets').subnetProperties[copyIndex('subnets')].name)",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnets').subnetProperties[copyIndex('subnets')].addressPrefix]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Param file:

```
"subnets":{
  "value":{
    "subnetProperties":[
      {
        "name":"firstSubnet",
        "addressPrefix":"10.0.0.0/24"
      },
      {
        "name":"secondSubnet",
        "addressPrefix":"10.0.1.0/24"
      }
    ]        
  }
},
```

I've also tried using copyIndex(), but that throws

```
 template language expression evaluation failed: 'The template language
function 'copyIndex' has an invalid argument. The provided copy name '' doesn't exist in the
resource.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you messed up with the brackets in this line:

`"name": "[parameters('subnets').subnetProperties[copyIndex('subnets')].name)",`

It should look like:

`"name": "[parameters('subnets').subnetProperties[copyIndex('subnets')].name]",`

The last bracket is wrong. If the brackets does not match the complete expression will not processed. This will result in the same name on the second loop.

Greetings,
KirK